# ASP.NET project still referencing old project name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I have this asp.net web application that I renamed.
I changed the assembly name, root namespace, changed all the aspx files Inherits lines to have  the new name.
But for some reason it is still references the old assembly name.  So the main page loads but there is a button that submits to pgRequest.aspx and I get this error in the event viewer.

Follow-up:
So I recreated the solution, project and did add existing item for all the forms.
I still get the issue.

Here is the code that submits from pgMain.aspx

```
        <form id="frmNew" name="frmNew" action="pgRequest.aspx" method="post" target="_blank">
            <input type="hidden" value="frmNew" name="hdnSource"><button id="cmdNewSubmit" name="cmdNewSubmit" type="submit" value="NEW"><IMG alt="Open Form" src="images/new.gif"><span class="button_message">Open New Form</span></button>
        </form>
```

Here is the error message from event viewer.

```
Could not load type 'Old_Name.pgRequest'.
--------------------
Could not load type 'Old_Name.pgRequest'.
Stack Trace:
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseReader(StreamReader reader, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse(ICollection referencedAssemblies, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
--------------------
Could not load type 'Old_Name.pgRequest'.
Stack Trace:
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
--------------------
Could not load type 'Old_Name.pgRequest'.
Stack Trace:
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData)

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Comment: Could it be namespaces? I never remember how VB.NET deals with them... Have you checked for any references to Old_Name in the proj file?

Comment: I did a text search for the old project name through all the files and removed any references to the old project name.  My next step is to  recreate the project and import all the files.

Comment: Did you remove the old dll from the bin folder? It will still try to load it if it finds it in there and that could be causing problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
While I changed the Inherits line of the page directive in the development source, it wasn't changed on the deployed version I was testing with.  Deploying the corrected aspx files solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must change ALL the names in every resource file.  Try using CTRL+F and typing the exact name then checking all the boxes below it and searching in the entire project.  That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the Microsoft ASP.net Temp files and it did work.
path:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

you check your version that at which version you are using and reset the IIS.